# Как можно вывести все элементы начинающиеся с определенного символа на JS?

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть определённые блоки:

```
<div class="Cat"> Cat </div>
<div class="Dog"> Dog </div>
<div class="Home"> Home </div>
<div class="Man"> Man </div>
<div class="result"> </div>
```

Как вывести (неважно куда, в консоль или в блок `result`), все слова начинающиеся допустим с символа "H"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// Выбираем все div-элементы 
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

var result = "";

// Итерация по выбранным элементам
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {

  // Получаем текстовое значение
  var text = els[i].innerText;

  // Проверяем, начинается ли текст с заданной литеры
  if (text.startsWith("H")) {
    result = result + text + " ";
  }
};
console.log(result);
document.getElementsByClassName('result')[0].innerText = result;
```

```css
div.result {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="Cat"> Cat </div>
<div class="Hope"> Hope </div>
<div class="Dog"> Dog </div>
<div class="Home"> Home </div>
<div class="Man"> Man </div>
<div class="result"> </div>
```

Comment: добавь описание как работает твой код, какие функции используются

Comment: При выводе в блок "result" с помощью 
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text;,почему то только последнее слово с указанном символом выводится

Comment: Можно ли как то изменить вывод text в блок result?

Comment: @Маркус Дополнил пример.

Comment: Спасибо за решение!!!
А можно, если не сложно, в двух словах сказать что происходит при
    result = result + text + " ";

по сути мы прибавляем переменную result значение которой ровно "" к переменной text, если её удалить то будет выводится только последнее слово.
Получается что здесь какой то цикл повторения? Или я ошибаюсь?
Ещё раз спасибо!!

Comment: @Маркус Все прозаичней: мы просто добавляем пробел на тот случай, когда требуемых слов будет более одного (дополнил пример таким случаем)